# page right column pushing under left column?

Tags: php, css, layout, html

I recently launched my new website and everything has been great, but all the sudden the right column has pushed itself under the left column and to the left. I don;t know what has caused this as nothing was changed and all the css/html looks the same compared to my other index files (I have a flat html index file that has no php in it for when I am building page layouts)

Here is my website: http://www.survivaloperations.net/

As you can see the right column has pushed its self down and to the left http://puu.sh/840fQ.jpg

I have been looking for almost an hour now trying to figure out the cause of this, and how to fix it (all the column widths are as they should be and match with my working index.html template file).

Any ideas/comments/suggestions are welcome and much appreciated!

Comment: What are you using to debug your layout? Your best way?

Comment: I have an index.html file of the layout that is working, and I am comparing the html in the index.php to that to see if it is an HTML related issue, and I can;t seem to find anything different. Then I use the F12 function (inspect element) to  check the size of each of the containers and divs to make sure something isnt 1px too wide causing the right col to push down.

Comment: Then in the inspect, are you adjusting the sizes?

Comment: I did on some, but it didnt seem to change anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I decrease `#left_col`'s width the right col pops up next to it.

update: when I remove the `overflow: auto` from the `.content_wrap` div element the menu seems to return to it's proper place.

update two:

I added a a div with the class `clearfix` that has the css style of `clear:both` after the floated columns and your footer returns to the bottom of the page:

```
<div class="content_wrap">
  <div id=left_col></div>
  <div id="right_col"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

when floating elements the parent element gets collapsed, thus why your footer was pushed up. Adding a clear:both is the general way to fix the collapsing div.

Comment: this positions it back to the right, but then cuts off the right side of the left column that news is in. This was all working properly up until about an hour and a half ago or so. I have no clue what caused it to break or why there is a scroll bar in the page now suddenly. (also doing your method don't remove the scroll bar)

Comment: you didnt mention that scroll bar so I didnt know you wanted to remove it or that it was unwanted.

When the page is at full-screen the menu and site looks good but once I narrow it's width the menu drops below the left_col.

I removed `overflow: auto` from the `.content_wrap` element and that might be the fix?

Comment: removing the overfolow: auto from the .content_wrap is something I had tried before, and it fixes the right column, but breaks the footer and other page stuff EX: http://puu.sh/842uH.jpg && http://puu.sh/842w5.jpg

Comment: if you add a div with the style of `clear:both` after the left_col and right_col div elements but inside of `.content_wrap` the footer will return to the bottom.

since the elements were floated the parent div `.content_wrap` gets collapsed.

Comment: I have done that, and the footer background is now being drawn, however it seems that the footer is not falling to the bottom like it should. http://puu.sh/846eo.jpg

Comment: what is funny is all of these things i have tried individually before posting, but it seems like the combination of these is what is fixing the issue. I wish i knew why it did this all the sudden, nothing was ever changed in the index or the css when this happened.

Comment: Nature of the beast, it happens to us all. Something creeps is when code gets pushed to production, gremlins!

Comment: Finally got it fixed. Turns out that one of my other developers added echo $path[1]; to the index file to try to troubleshoot another issue we were having the other day and it caused the layout to go haywire, so all the stuff I have been trying was for nothing, because none of it was the problem... My head hurts!

Comment: oh man. Well good job on figuring it out! Treat yourself something. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Check for float: right, right-padding, margin-right in your CSS as well as your inline 
>   styling if you have any. Do a right click and inspect element to see what styles are 
>   being inherited. If content has changed, the above three can be affected.